# Paypal: Submit button no longer redirects to Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a bespoke shopping cart that uses Paypal via the sandbox. All works well in the sandbox but when I moved the site to the production site (note site not live just yet) it no longer redirects to the Paypal site on submit. The only things to have changed are:

- New site has SSL old site did not
- Cookies changed to reflect this SSL

The PHP error I get is:

PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at xxxx/layout_head.php:27) in xxx/process_paypal.php on line 147

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who are seeking an answer to this I found out that my hosting site has "output_buffering" in the "php.ini" not set so I set it with the following:

output_buffering = 4096

The redirect works now. Not sure of the security implications of this so if someone knows of any security concerns please respond to this answer